# Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest host

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am creating a whitelist for google APIs and need the host for Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest because I am running it in cloud code. I tried `*parse.com*` but that is apparently not where the cloud request comes from. What is the host for Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest?

Comment: Why not to use Webhooks for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up a simple cloud code function to fetch my webpage and watched the incoming traffic. The requests are apparently coming from Amazon AWS. So, if you want, you can white-list all incoming traffic from `*.amazonaws.com*`. Though it is still pretty wide, it's better than nothing. I guess.

Here are some of the "hosts" the requests were coming from:

```
ec2-54-85-239-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com.52367
ec2-54-85-238-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com.58376
ec2-54-85-239-177.compute-1.amazonaws.com.55239
```

Hope that clarifies it a bit.